# Handling password updates in Java SSL

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, passwords

I have a client-server java application, where communication happens over SSL. Right now I am generating keypairs by hand, but I need a programmatic system for key management.

The server maintains a user database, and on the client side I do not want to store a copy of the password. Somehow the client will log in to the server using a password. If the password is correct, the server and client will set up keys. From then on they can use those keys and not have to use the password. This brings me to my first question:

- When the user enters the password the first time, how do I encrypt that transmission? Because there will be no keys and thus no SSL at this point.

Then there is the issue of the user changing their password. The idea is they will go through a web interface to change their password on the server. Then the next time a client connects, their old keys should not work and they should be asked to enter the new password. Which brings me to my next question:

- What is the best practice for
  handling the password change when
  dealing with SSL?

I can just delete the server side key when they change their password. Then the client wont be able to communicate, and then I can have the client ask for a new password. But it seems a little kludgey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still can have SSL between client and server. In fact, you should.

The server won't be able to trust the client yet. Client can trust the server, because the server certificate is available to the client.

For example, look how most logins on web are implemented: you are not authenticated yet, but you're going into HTTPS. This is one-way SSL. Client is using a temporal key. Password is passed over the encrypted connection. This protects from eavesdropping.

When the mutual trust (through validation of the password) is established, you can pass client certificate over the same connection and reset the session. From that moment you'll have a two-way SSL, a mutual trust.

**UPDATE**

I see a bit of confusion in the thread due to not clear wording of "requirements". Let me write down the collaboration between client and server:

Session 1:

1. Client needs to talk to server
2. Client generates a temporal pair of private and public key
3. Client connects to server via SSL and passes public key to server for the session
4. Client receives server public key/certificate and compares it to one it knows a priori; bail out if mismatched.
5. One-way SSL connection has been established at this point; client knows for sure it talks to server, while server doesn't know the identity of the client. The connection is encrypted though.
6. Client passes in credentials (userid and password, likely).
7. Server validates them and bails out if they do not match.
8. Server now trusts the client is, say, John Smith from Nebraska.
9. Client asks server to store current public key as client permanent public key OR generates another key pair and sends the public one to server (I do not see a problem to use the same key, but I may be overlooking something).
10. End of session.

Session 2:

1. Client connects to server over SSL
2. Client provides its public key/certificate
3. Server compares it to the one stored on server side
4. Server provides its public key/certificate
5. Client compares it to the known one.
6. Mutual trust has been established, connection is encrypted, server knows the client is John Smith from Nebraska.
7. Still, to be on the safe side, server may still request John to enter the password.

Comment: ah. So I can initiate the SSL discussion without keys? Is this how SSH does it pre-password?

Comment: Public key encryption requires two public keys exchanged. But none of them required to be permanent (though server key should be known and better be verified by the client).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am going to wait a bit to accept in case an answer comes in today for my second question. Meanwhile I will look online for an example of doing this two stage SSL where the server can be connected and determine if the client is authenticated or not.

Comment: SSH and SSL are two completely different protocols, which happen to share two letters in their acronyms.

Comment: Most importantly, they share the principle -- public key encryption, and that's what Jono meant, I believe.

Comment: Right. Thanks for your update. Now I think I understand the concept, and I just need to figure out how to code it.

Answer (score 1):

While an SSL connection *can* authenticate the client using a client-side certificate, it's most often used only to authenticate the *server* and to create an encrypted connection between an identified server (by virtue of a certificate tied to a domain name), and an anonymous client.

To use client certificates the *client* must generate the PKCS key-pair, a certificate signing request and get it signed by an authority that the server trusts.  Absent that process, authentication of the client is typically done be a protocol on top of SSL which requires some secret that only the client knows.  This is typically a password, such as a good ol' website login.

*Conversely*, what you are describing is actually a machine generated ephemeral (out of thin air) ***password*** (these are often called "keys", but it's important that you understand it's really just a special password).  That is, after an initial connection authenticated with a password typed by the user, you send the client an ephemeral password to store and use for subsequent connections.

To handle password change, you simply need to change your protocol to allow the ephemeral password. If it's not correct but the server has one, you might want to lock the account, assuming a hack attempt (though that can be a DoS opening).  Otherwise, if it's not correct because the server has no ephemeral key (i.e. the server side has blanked it because the password was changed), then you simple send a response to the client to challenge the user for the current password.  The user then enters the password, and assuming it matches, the server then generates and transmits a new ephemeral password.

EDIT: To clarify, even though your are generating PKCS key-pairs, without doing that client-side and binding them into a certificate, this is not client-side certificate authentication.  It's merely a cryptographically strong machine generated ephemeral ***password***.

And, beware, that at the end of the day, your system is only as strong as the initial password which caused the key-pair to be generated (or, subsequently, replaced).

Comment: Good explanation, but from the Jono wording I understood that a user chooses and uses the password.

Comment: @road: The user logs into the server, which then generates a client key... which key is nothing more than a machine generated password.  He doesn't say how that ephemeral password gets into the client application; I am presuming he builds the password authentication and change into the client.  Otherwise, you might have a simple copy/paste from a website to the client application.  But he needs to do something to make the client app aware of the generated password.

Comment: But why the machine-generated password needed? There is a client password, and a client-generated key pair. Why another password? I'm missing something here.

Comment: What you are missing is that there *isn't* any client certificate.

Comment: Uh, so what Jono says "I generate keypairs by hand", he means the server cert only? Why plural then? OK, suppose there is no client cert. But there is a client password. Client needs to enter it every time they log in over one-way SSL. How yet another password helps?

Comment: The user creates their account (and sets and changes the password) through a web site. I am not concerned with the web SSL. My question is about the Java client and server SSL. The user defined password lives on the server only. The user should only have to enter it when the client talks to the server after a password has been changed or an account has been created. Once the password is OKed by the server, appropriate keys should be transferred/created. The user defined password should not be stored anywhere on the client machine and should never need it once proper keys have been exchanged.

Comment: Reading you answer makes me realize I understand far less about SSL public keys then I thought and I need to do some more reading. For now I will say that there is no "authority that the server trusts". I am building an application with client and server components. Anyone can install the server. So there is not only one that is to be trusted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since using SSL for client authentication requires keys to already be shared, you have two choices: either don't use SSL to provide client authentication, or renegotiate after delivering the client certificate to the client.

In the first model, on first connection, the client first connects over SSL with no client auth, then issues a login command of some sort, and receives a session token. At that point, the server knows that the other party on that SSL connection is that particular user. If the client wishes to reconnect later, it just present that session token to authenticate itself at the start of that second connection (still over SSL, but not using client auth). In this model, revocation of sessions can be done by deleting the server's notion of the session.

In the second model, the the server responds to the login command by providing a client cert that it signs. From there, the client will renegotiate the connection using the new certificate. In this model, revocation can be done by using something akin to a certificate revocation list (keep this from growing too big by using moderate expirations on the certificates).

Comment: In model #1: a man in the middle intercepts the second login attempt, snatches the token, blocks user connections and logs in instead of him from his own connection.

Comment: In model #2: no reason for server to provide the client cert. In fact, it is impossible without security risks, as to generate the cert one need to generate the private key too. Client has to generate the cert and pass it to server - over the one-way SSL connection with trust established by password. Server stores it and revokes if needed.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear: the further communication in model 1 would still be over SSL. As for the security risk of transmitting a private key: you're transmitting that key over the same encrypted channel you just transmitted the password which that key speaks for.

Comment: If the second connection in model #1 is over SSL too, what's the point to have an extra token? Wouldn't password as in first connection do just the same? In fact, this is description of normal password-based login protected by one-way SSL. Token is not needed.

Comment: @road to yamburg renegotiation has been reimplemented to prevent rouge intermediate services forcing an unsafe renegotiation request.

Comment: @Yuliy I didn't know that a client could request to identify itself with a certificate via ssl.  I thought that only the server could request the client to authenticate itself via the servers client authentication = true or required depending on the server's technology.

Comment: This is called two-way SSL. Both sides have to know each other.

Comment: @hooknc - the server can either require the client to present a certificate, or it can say that it is optional. In this case, the server would always say that a client certificate is optional, and expect a login if no valid client certificate is presented.

@road to yamburg The point of the extra token is to prevent having to store a (cleartext or symmetrically encrypted) password on the client